# Replicating models across 2 systems

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 systems which are seperate from each other.  To let them communicate I have built an API.  Both systems have common Models, one of which is a Project Model with all its relationships.

Within System A, to send a Project with its relationships I do the following.

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$jsonProject = json_encode(Project::with('projectType', 'projectType.projectTypeData',
                            'projectAssets', 'projectAssets.projectAssetsData')->find($project->id));

$req = $client->request('POST', 'https://someurl/postProject', [
    'body' => json_encode($jsonProject),
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Length' => strlen($jsonProject),
    ]
]);
```

Within System B I have the routes set up, and when the above is posted the following is triggered

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $project = $request->all();
    dd($project);
}
```

When I make the post request from System A I see something like this because of the dump in System B (I have removed a lot of the output to cut down on code).

```
array:17 [
  "id" => 3
  "projectName" => "Test Project"
  "user_id" => 1
  "contact" => "John Doe"
  "project_type" => array:7 [
    "id" => 3
    "project_id" => 3
    "project_type_data" => array:1 [
      0 => array:8 [
        "id" => 5
        "projectType" => "Standard"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "project_assets" => array:7 [
    "id" => 2
    "project_id" => 3
    "project_assets_data" => array:4 [
      0 => array:8 [
        "id" => 5
        "label" => "Logo"
        "altTag" => ""
        "urlPath" => ""
        "projectAssetsId" => 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

So everything seems to work fine.  My question is this.  System B now has a load of json data containing all the data required to make the models.  If I was able to send a model via the api (not json) then I could easily create the model within System B.  Because it is json data however, and I cant decode it because it is not a string, do I have to start looping it all in order to make my models?

Comment: I would be very interested to know more about your specific situation. Since I don't have more details I don't know for sure, but it seems fishy that you want to have two systems interacting with the same data and the same models in this way, it seems like there should be a better solution...

Comment: But anyway since the array being returned has both the keys and values you could in theory just call Model::create on the array of attributes without having to manually loop them. (NOT saying this is a good idea!)

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  It's actually an interesting situation.  When a client sends me a project it is in Excel form generally, and I input the data into my internal system.  Instead of this, I thought what if I build the client a similar platform to mine where they can enter the required details and it is feed into my system.  My system is a lot more advanced, and I don't want the client system to be exposed to anything in my system directly.  As such, I am building a client system which connects to mine via an API.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Maybe I'm not understanding fully, but this seems like a very typical situation requiring roles and permissions.. Sites all the time need to hide/protect certain data or certain parts of the application. Why can't you have one system, with roles and permissions set up to restrict the client to whatever you want to give him access to?

Comment: Hi, I have roles and permissions but my internal system is on a special server with lots of restrictions.  I need to treat them like 2 seperate systems.  The client also wants their own system which can grow, not have a slot on our system.  Lots of politics :-)

Comment: Ok, I'm still not entirely convinced there isn't an alternative, but I'll leave you to that and try to get to answering the question you have posed. I'm not entirely sure I understand the issue though, are you trying to get the data from the API and then create a model in your system with that data? Or are you trying to pass an actual model instance over through the api? or what?

Comment: To be honest, whatever is best.  Is it possible to pass the Model via the API?  I was searching for this but could not find an answer.

Comment: We should move this to chat if you have further comments. If forced to use two systems, I would not try to treat them as one system, because it is possible that one system will change while the other will not. Therefore, I would actually recommend explicitly copying over all the data (i.e. creating a new model and setting its attributes to the data received from the api), rather than trying to get the exact model from a different system. This way, if api system changes, your other system either doesn't break or at least gives a clear picture why it broke.